# WPF dynamically scale TextBlock Text without filling a container

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a set of pages that look like this:

[image]

I have the content in grids with * Heights and Widths so the grid correctly scales when the entire window resizes. I would like the text to resize with the grid. Basically I would like the user to resize from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

(preserving white space)

One way to do this would be to wrap the `TextBlock` in a `ViewBox` with margins on the right and bottom (for `Grid.Row="3"`) to account for white space. But because I have several pages with different lengths and line counts I would have to set the margin specifically for each page otherwise the text sizes would differ on each page. Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: Although this is sort of opinion based as asked I think the question could easily be improved to ask what alternatives exist and how they compare to viewbox. I don't see why a different margin is necessary for each page.

Comment: thanks for the edit! I don't have enough rep to post images directly yet xd

Comment: You risk your question being closed unless you change it. There are 2 votes already.

Comment: Different margins are needed because the lyrics on each page have different lengths. With the same margin, the text size on each page will therefore also be different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way to do this. There are different ways. But, I think it isn't just a matter of opinion that they would not be better.

Ways I can think of.

Render your text offscreen, rendertargetbitmap that so you've got a picture. Change your textblocks on screen to images and stretch them.

Or

Work out the size your text wants to be. Then do some calculation comes up with a different fontsize which is "better".  This is a lot easier to write a description of than do.

In my opinion.

A viewbox is easier to implement. Way less error prone than calculations. Will give at least as good results as rendering to a picture.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the suggestion! Worst case I'll replace it with images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add one more solution to the ones suggested by Andy, which is more of a scientific approach and takes a bit of practice to master.

Suppose you have to find a function F, which maps one or more variables to a desired single value. In your case that would be a function F, which takes aspect ratio of the window as input and outputs an appropriate font size.

How can you find such a function? 
Well... you don't need to do any math yourself!

First, you need some data to begin with:

```
1. Resize the window randomly
2. Calculate aspect ration (X)
3. Pick an appropriate font size that looks good enough (Y)
4. Repeat the measurement 7 to 10 times (sorry data scientists)
5. Enter the data in Excel - one column for X and another one for Y
6. Insert a scatter chart
7. Choose the best trendline for your data, but avoid the polynomial one
8. Display the trendline equation and use the expression in your code
```

Now I should mention the pros and cons of this regression technique.

Pros:

```
1. It can solve a wide range of tricky problems:
   "I use this 3rd party control, but when the text is too long it overlaps the title bar. How to trim it so it doesn't go beyond the top border?. Deadline is coming!"
2. Even if it doesn't solve the problem perfectly, the results are often acceptable
3. It takes minutes to try out unlike spending a day refreshing your math skills
```

Cons:

```
1. The biggest problem is that to keep it simple, you often lower the number of 
   variables by assuming some of them to be constant. In this post I've assumed that 
   the font family won't change for example, neither the font weight.
2. If any of the assumptions does not hold the final result could be even worse
```

This technique is fragile, but powerful. Use it as your last weapon and never leave magic expression like
fontSize = (int)(0.76 + 1.2 * aspectRation) without documenting how it came to be.

Comment: interesting method, a lot more difficult to implement than other solutions. You'd have to monitor the state of the window as the user can change the window size at any given time => dynamically calculating the aspect ratio. Very cool idea though, I'll be sure to bookmark it, might come in handy later on. Thanks!